# Remote login from an unnamed fields using Guzzle PHP

Tags: php, authentication, guzzle

There is a specific site that I would like to connect to remotely through Guzzle. The problem whose fields of username and password are without a name.

**My question is:**

1. Can I use POST method without knowing the names of the fields?
2. Can I use the name of the class instead?

**My code:**

Login.php

```
<?php
require("master/guzzle/vendor/autoload.php");

$username = "abc";
$password = "123456";

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$response = $client->post('https://www.exmaple.com/login', [
    'body' => [
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password,
        'action' => 'login'
    ],
    'cookies' => true
]
);

echo $response;
?>
```

example.com/login

```
<form>
    <div class="login-name">
        <div data-nep="Label" class="name-font default neptune_block_15yk4 neptune_LABEL-STANDARD_1h3i4">Username
            <div class="neptune_fade-after_15yk4"></div>
        </div>
        <div data-nep="TextBox">
            <input type="text" placeholder="" value="" class="neptune_default_1jbvk" style="height:30px">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="login-name">
            <div data-nep="Label" class="name-font default neptune_block_15yk4 neptune_LABEL-STANDARD_1h3i4">Password
                <div class="neptune_fade-after_15yk4"></div>
            </div>
            <div data-nep="TextBox">
                <input type="password" placeholder="" value="" class="neptune_default_1jbvk" style="height:30px">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Is it a ajax login form? if so, I think after entering data in fileds, the form will call a Ajax call of original login controller. so you must find that request and post parameters name

Comment: Could be but i cant find any Ajax code in the site... Can I use the name of the class instead? @mehdijalilvand

Comment: I dont think so. may i see the url of the login page?

Comment: the login page calls the ajax request `https://api.moodys.com/rest/mobile/oauth/token?client=0` with 3 parameters:
username,
grant_type='password',
password

Comment: Are you trying to scrape Moodys information?  I support a number of products for Moodys, if you work for Moodys I encourage you to reach out to your support group, we can help you in house.

If you don't.... create your own content, stop scraping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it a ajax login form? if so, I think after entering data in fileds, the form will call a Ajax call of original login controller. so you must find that request and post parameters name

Use Firefox or chrome press F12 to show the Web Developer toos, go to the Network panel and select `XHR` to filter ajax request.

In your case when submitting the form there is a callback to another page
click on `params` tab on the right will show you what post data your looking for.

[image: Sample ScreenShot]

```
$response = $client->request('POST', 'https://api.moodys.com/rest/mobile/oauth/token?client=0', [
    'form_params' => [
        'username' => 'test@gmail.com',
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'password' => 'testpassword',
    ]
])
```

Comment: This is not an answer, please comment under question instead.

Comment: @AymDev I think this is the answer, he was looking for the key in the wrong place ;) and this answer can help others who have same problem.

Comment: Could you edit your answer and put a code (with Guzzle) how to do it correctly.. because i tried it with your 3 parameters and it is not working...